# MPI_Gather with only 1 rank

Tags: c, mpi

I was wondering if  it is possible to use MPI_Gather with only one MPI process. The example below run with just 1 MPI rank, the commented out code works well, however it does not work with the `MPI_Gather`.

What can possibly be wrong with this?

```
    // for (i = 0; i< column; i++)
    //   {
    //  for ( j = 0; j< row; j++)
    //    {
    //      new[i][j] = old[i][j] ;      
    //    }
    //   }


    MPI_Gather(&old[0][0], column*row, MPI_INT,
               &new[0][0], column*row, MPI_INT,
               0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: If you have a communicator with only one process then I can see no reason why a correctly formed call to `MPI_Gather` should not work.  But why would you want to do that ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark No reason, but I need to make sure it works with 1 before I run it on multiple processes.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I should probably mention, `old` is `INT` and `new` is `UNSIGNED_CHAR`. Does this matter?

Comment: Wlcome to Stackoverflow ! Yes, it could matter. An UNSIGNED_CHAR is likely one byte, while an INT is likely 4. The MPI_Gather will attempt to copy the INT array `old` in the smaller one `new`, thus inducing an undefined behavior, such as segmentation fault. As `new[i][j] = old[i][j] ;` There is an implicit cast from INT to UNSIGNED CHAR. While the code works well, it might face some overflow some day. MPI_Gather() will not perform this cast: the  memory footprint of the output must match that of the input.

Comment: @francis Interesting, it seems that the casting works. So if I copy `old` to an `unsigned char` array and use it instead of `old` then works. Is there a way of casting `old` without copying it to a different array?